# The ckeditor toolbar missing

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I made a custom ckeditor but I had all the basic things plus a few more. I've been trying to use ckeditor and tried both by both replacing textarea element by class name and by javascript code, but in both situations, all I get in my textarea is [image: this]

My code for it is here:

```
{{ Form::textarea('LONG_DESCRIPTION', $article->LONG_DESCRIPTION, ['class' => 'edito', 'id'=>'editor1']) }}
                        <script src="/*****/vendor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
                        <script>
                          CKEDITOR.replace('editor1',
                             {
                                 toolbar: 'MyToolbar'
                             });

                        </script>
```

And this is the config file just in case:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
    config.toolbar = 'MyToolbar';

    config.toolbar_MyToolbar =
    [
        { name: 'document', items : [ 'NewPage','Preview' ] },
        { name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
        { name: 'editing', items : [ 'Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','-','Scayt' ] },
        { name: 'insert', items : [ 'Image','Flash','Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar','PageBreak'
                 ,'Iframe' ] },
                '/',
        { name: 'styles', items : [ 'Styles','Format' ] },
        { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Strike','-','RemoveFormat' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote' ] },
        { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink','Anchor' ] },
        { name: 'tools', items : [ 'Maximize','-','About' ] }
    ];
};
```

What am I doing wrong or have wrong for it not to work and just appear as that in the image?